# AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`

Tags: flutter

After upgrading to Flutter 2.10, I get the following error:

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
The detected reason was:

  /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

I've already upgraded to Flutter embedding 2.  How to solve this error?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting `android:name` to

`android:name="${applicationName}"` in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
```

Apparently Flutter 2.10 has stricter checks than previous versions.

Comment: I did this too when migrating from Flutter 1.22.6 to 2.2.3 and this change caused the build to fail, because `applicationName` is not found anywhere. The "Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects" guide doesn't even say anything about this line other than "do it". And in Flutter projects created with Flutter 2.2.3 onwards, this line does not exist anymore, probably because it's optional (see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm)).

Answer (score 9):

[image: Android manifest file]

complete guideline please [click](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)

Answer (score 7):

there is two solutions

first solution, you can replace

`android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`

with

`android:name="${applicationName}"`

the second solution, remove

`android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`

and run your code

Answer (score 5):

open your AndroidManifest.xml just remove this line`android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"`

Comment: The only that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

may be you are working on an old version of Flutter so you faced this problem and maybe you'll face another problems so let's discuss them

1- in this path

`{App Dir}\android\app\src\main\AndroidMainfest.xml`

you'll find attribute `android:name` the problem is in its value so we should change it
`android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"`
convert it to =>
`android:name="${applicationName}"`

2- in this path
`{App Dir}\android\build.gradle`

you will find this line `ext.kotlin_version = 'XXXXXX'`

so you should update it to the latest version of kotlin

you can find it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)
so latest version for me in 06 JULY 2022 is `1.7.0`

i put it in my project and it was `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'`

i hope that i helped you