# build failed due to use of deprecated android v1 embedding when cloning a project from github

Tags: flutter, android-studio

cloning project from GitHub fails and gives this error. I tried modifying things in AndroidManifest.xml and in java and nothing helps. please I'm been struggling with this for couple of days now so please help

Comment: You will need to migrate the project, hope this link helps. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#full-flutter-app-migration

Answer (score 7):

In my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml I changed android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" to android:name="${applicationName}"

The question was answered here: [AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019822/androidmanifest-xml-uses-androidname-io-flutter-app-futterapplication)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to run a old project is

1. remove android folder
2. flutter create . . it will create all dependent folder by default according to compatible settings